# Can itertools allow for list to be created from multiple lists where I set a limit to how many selections per list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, generator, python-itertools

I have a list of lists that I am using itertools.product with, but I would not like to limit the selection to 1 item per list. Is there a way to allow it to limit 3 from one list, 2 from the next list, and so on?

The list are of varying sizes as well within a list.

for example:

[[1,2,3,4,5],[4,6,45,2,5],[6,5,8,4,47,34],[5,7,23,8,3,10]]

I would like to be able to select the following amounts from the lists:

3, 4, 1, 2

Each number can only be selected one time per group per iteration.

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Which 3 numbers from the first list, etc?

Comment: Would selecting 3 from the first list include `1, 1, 1` or only distinct elements?

Comment: It would be 3 distinct numbers from the first list. I will adjust the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new longer list of lists, by repeating existing lists as required, and passing that longer list to `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

def multi_product(lists, repeats):
    repeated_iterables = [
        lst
        for lst, repeat in zip(lists, repeats)
        for i in range(repeat)
    ]
    return product(*repeated_iterables)
```

Alternatively, you can use a 2-layer `product`:

```
from itertools import product

def flatten(lst):
    return [ x for it in list for x in it ]

def multi_product(lists, repeats):
    producted = [ product(lst, repeat) for lst, repeat in zip(lists, repeats) ]
    return ( flatten(x) for x in product(*producted) )
```

The use of `flatten` guarantees you get a simple flat list back, but if you want the values to be "grouped" by the originating list, you can drop it. The solution in this case is simpler:

```
def multi_product(lists, repeats):
    producted = [ product(lst, repeat) for lst, repeat in zip(lists, repeats) ]
    return product(*producted)
```

Comment: Ty for this. I will check this answer tonight.

Comment: I think you need to use a `combination` rather than a `product` for the inner level, since repeats from the same list are not wanted.